# How to perform a set of action after a Dataflow pipeline is completed?

Tags: callback, google-cloud-dataflow, pipeline, apache-beam

Is it possible to get a callback after once DataFlow pipline is completed ? 
After the pipeline is completed I have to make some configuration changes to the system to use new Output generated by the pipeline and some other cleanup too. 
Now I am actually using the `waitUntilFinish()` function to halt the program flow and do the configuration changes after that. So while test running in the local system, it halt the developers command prompt or the user have to wait for pipeline to complete.

So is there a better way to do it ? Like a callback mechanism ?

Answer (score 0):

Their are no callback registry in dataflow out of the box.

However, you can set custom alert on stackdriver which can alert you once the pipeline is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Beam provides **Stop Bundle** and **[Teardown](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.Teardown.html)** methods amongst other lifecycle methods you can perhaps leverage to perform your task.

Answer (score 0):

I send myself an http request in my final transform:

```
import requests
def on_complete(callback_url):
    def _on_complete(element):
        r = requests.post(callback_url)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            # handle error
return _on_complete
```

Pipeline code:

```
_ = (p
     # ... my other transforms
     | 'count outputs' >> apache_beam.combiners.Count.Globally()
     | 'on complete' >> apache_beam.Map(on_complete(callback_url)))
```

I do `'count outputs'` to ensure `'on complete'` only receives a single element